# what happens to outdated questions?

Tags: discussion

There is this question:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78806/what-all-happens-when-you-hit-level-15-playing-a-trial-account

Which was good for its time and got 19 upvotes. And its answer got 18 upvotes. Now the game has gone free to play, and the question is no longer relevant. It can't be edited to show relevancy, for obvious reasons, and is about to be closed. What will happen to the reputation for this question and answer once it's deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a post is at least 60 days old (which that one is) and has a score of at least 3 (which both the question and accepted answer have), when they are deleted the owner will retain all rep gained from the post.